# Is $i$ a 3rd root of $-i$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I was asked to find the 3rd root of -i. Now, since $i^3 = -i$ I thought that I can just extract the 3rd root out of both sides and get $\root3\of{i^3} = \root3\of{-i} \implies i = \root3\of{-i}$. Searching Google and Wolfram Alpha, I found that $\root3\of{-i}=0.866025404-0.5i$.

The question is: is $i$ a cube root of $-i$ as well? (P.S.: This might be a silly question, but I have just started studying complex numbers).

Comment: Similarly to what happens for real numbers with even exponents, $\sqrt[3]{x^3}=x$ is *not* an identity that holds in the complex variable, mainly because, since the equation $x^3-\alpha=0$ always has exactly three solutions in $\Bbb C$ for all $\alpha\ne 0$, a choice must be made in defining a section of the function $z\mapsto z^3$. It goes without saying that the assertion "$x^3=\alpha$ if and only if $x=\sqrt[3]\alpha$" does not hold either.

Comment: $$\sqrt[3]{-i}=\sqrt[3]{e^{-\pi i/2}}=e^{-\pi i/6}=\frac{\sqrt3}2-\frac i2$$

Comment: What I wonder: why are you doubting your results? You know the definition of cube root and you know that $i^3=-i$, so what reasons might be there for $i$ to not be a cube root of $-i$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $i$ is one of the three cube roots of $-i$. To find the others, you can factor
$$x^3+i=x^3-i^3=(x-i)(x^2+ix+i^2)=(x-i)(x^2+ix-1)$$
and now you can find the other two roots by solving the quadratic equation $x^2+ix-1=0$.

More simply, the three cube roots of $-i$ are $i$, $i\omega$, and $i\omega^2$, where
$$\omega=\cos120^\circ+i\sin120^\circ=-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$$
is a primitive cube root of $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let simply check that

$$i\times i = -1 \implies i\times i \times i= -1\times i=-i$$

indeed $z^3=-i$ has exactly three solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ and one is $z=i$.

Comment: Gimusi.Welcome back.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Hi Peter. Thanks! I lost your message yesterday. I've raised a thread on Meta on my suspension. If you are interested to give a look to it take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29254/505767). Bye

Comment: Gimusi.I do not get what it us all about.Happy that you are back, and looking forward to reading your solutions.Cheers.;)

Comment: @PeterSzilas It is just a discussion about the common rules we need to follow in order to make ME a better place. But of course you do not need any suggestion about that for your genuine friendliness. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens that every non-zero complex numbers has $3$ cube roots.

In your case, since $i=\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)i$, those cube roots will be$$\cos\left(\frac\pi6\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi6\right)i,\ \cos\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right)+\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right)i\text{ and }\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)+\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)i(=-i).$$